# What part do I need to search for to fix this leaky outdoor hose faucet?

Tags: water, faucet, hose, gardening

When I turn on the hose outside my house, pictured below, water pours out of the top of it and goes all over the place.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this without having to replace the whole thing? Does anyone recognize this component and can recommend a part ?

[image: leaky water house faucet]

And here is what it looks like off:
[image: waterhoseoff]

[image: water hose cover off]

[image: water hose faucet it]

[image: water hose faucet side logo id]

Comment: Can you turn that top piece clockwise and tighten it up?  It looks like an extra port on the spigot.

Comment: I tightened it all the way, this is what it looks like

Comment: Can you turn off the water and remove that piece? Maybe a washer is missing inside.

Comment: As Jack stated, it looks like another hose connection without a hose connected to it.  With the water off, can you provide a pic of the end or top of the part that is leaking.

Comment: @JACK has the answer, you need a hose washer under that cap...

Comment: @JACK I've added a photo of under the cap. Thank for the help

Comment: It seems like there sure should be a rubber washer in there. did it just start leaking ?

Comment: It's the first time I'm using it since moving in

Comment: The top part is a backflow preventer valve that is broken, Would need to know the brand or a picture showing the brand marking to determine how or what part to repair. Your faucet appears to be similar to [this]( https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prier-Products-1-2-in-x-24-in-Brass-MPT-x-SWT-Heavy-Duty-Frost-Free-Anti-Siphon-Outdoor-Faucet-Hydrant-C-144D24/204740182).

Comment: @Programmer66 I added more photos. It's unclear what the brand is

Comment: no logo on the other side?

Comment: Nope no logo there

Comment: Added a possible part replacement in ans

Comment: Those of you from warm climates who don't know what a vacuum breaker is should clean up your comments. They're off the mark.

Comment: The faucets as listed by the various OEM uses both terms, anti-siphon and/or vacuum breaker in their listing in their description and replacement part useages for the same item. So it is a little difficult to state the reason for this faucet, to prevent backflow into the portable water line or to prevent freezing or what the correct term should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anti-siphon part on top is broken.  You need to determine the brand and purchase the replacement part for the anti-siphon.
The brand can be seen here.  Take a photo of the brand here.
[image]

For the similiar style shown in my comment earlier, a replacement part is sold.  If your faucet is a PRIER or Mansfield, this is the part needed.

[image]

You would order a similar part/kit for your brand.

You can unscrew the plastic part,  It is most likely cracked to gush that much water.  Try this universal replacement part shown in this Youtube video.

Replacing part with [universal repair kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9NQFo4-OeU)

I found this part, which looks identical to your photo. Remove the plastic piece and see if it looks like this.

[image]
IF the right blue handle is turned inline with the outlet, water should come out, even if the top cap is leaking.

This part can be [purchase here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Vacuum-Breaker-Kit-for-Frost-Free-Valves-888-183/100157182).

[image]

You stated you didn't want to replace the whole fixture, It might be easier (@ more cost) to replace the whole faucet with a similar type.
Another solution is to replace the broken faucet with a standard hose faucet, and add a vacuum breaker part on the hose bib end.

Comment: So to summarize, you reckon I just need to purchase that part you linked to ?

Comment: Yes,  unscrew the plastic part from your faucet, it should look similar to the part I showed in my Ans.  If it looks the same or similar purchase the part and try it.  If it does not, post a picture of the piece that you removed so we have a better understanding of the part that is needed. after removal, you should be able to tell why it is failing (leaking)

Comment: Thank you I'm going to make a trip to Home Depot and update you

Comment: This may be stupid, but open up the two lower blue valves and see if it still leaks.  To open, turn the handle in line with the hose outlets.

Comment: It does nothing when those two are turned. Only the top big blue valve causes the leak

Comment: Ok, water should come out of the faucet when the lower two handle are turned inline (vertical) to the faucet as well at the top leaking.

Comment: Yes water is coming out through the hose while the leak goes on

Comment: Take the part with you when you go to HD

Comment: do you have any idea how to screw the thing back in? I unscrewed with pliars but that damaged the ridges on the old one – CodyBugstein just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Did you purchase the replacement part?  Why would you need to put the old part back in?

Comment: I have to put the new part in, but it has to be screwed in, and it's not easy to do by hand

Comment: You should be able to start the screwing in by hand, and then just pliers (squeezing lightly) to finish the seating.  Make sure, the plunger is still center in the top part when screwing down, otherwise it will be preventing the top plastic piece from screwing in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it cracked most common cause is; the water wasn t turned off and the hose wasn t disconnect during cold weather. Just suggestion for the future.

Comment: Where do you see a crack ?